# NoSuchElementException with Scanner class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I have a problem with Scanner class that must retrieve some data from the console, here is the code:

```
private static int getInputFromTheConsole() {
    System.out.println("Enter one of the menu options.");
//    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
//    return sc.nextInt();
    try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        return Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

When I use two commented lines then it works fine, but when I use Scanner with try-with-resources than it throws `NoSuchElementException`.
When I try to debug program Scanner in try-catch block simply does not wait for input, but as I said before with commented lines of code it works fine.
Why it happens?

Comment: Try-with-resources closes its resource, here Scanner instance, which means also closing its source of data, here System.in, which is why you can't read from it anymore.

Comment: Why don't you use sc.nextInt() instead ?

Comment: You should have only one Scanner which should read from System.in. You can pass it to other methods, but those methods shouldn't close it (unless you are sure that you will no longer need to read from System.in).

Answer (score 0):

[NoSuchElementException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) Thrown by the nextElement method of an Enumeration to indicate that there are no more elements in the enumeration.

So you can check if there is any input by calling [Scanner.hasNextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) method. For example

```
if(sc.hasNextInt() )
     input = sc.nextInt();
```